# How to convert seconds beginning from 1904 to datetime in golang?

Tags: go, time

Go has a `time.Unix` function which converts seconds to datetime.

`Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.`

Is there a function which can convert seconds from 1904?

Basically in need to convert seconds beginning from 1904 `3400769156` to datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existing function, but creating one yourself isn't that hard:

```golang
func since1904ToTime(sec int64) time.Time {
    return time.Date(1904, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local).Add(time.Second*time.Duration(sec))
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works for 290 years around 1904, because the valid range for time.Duration is approx. ±290 years. If you need wider range, there are other (less readable) alternatives.